# Opening Multiple Pages with Mechanize in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to open multiple pages following a certain format using mechanize. I want to start with a certain page, and have mechanize follow all the links that have a certain class or piece of text in a link. For example, the root url would be something like

`http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/offices/prime-minister`

and I want to follow every link on the page that has a format such as

```
<li class='office-holder'><a href="http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/people/mr-tony-blair">Mr Tony Blair</a> May  2, 1997 - June 27, 2007</li>
```

In other words, I want to follow every link that has the class 'office-holder' or that has /people/ in the URL. I've tried the following code, but it hasn't worked.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/offices/prime-minister")
links = br.links(url_regex="/people/")

print links
```

I'm trying to print the links so I can make sure that I'm getting the right links/information before writing any more code. The error(?) I get from this is:

```
<generator object _filter_links at 0x10121e6e0>
```

Any pointers or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error - it means that `Browser.links()` returns an generator object rather than a list.

An [iterator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) is an object that acts "like a list", meaning that you can do things like

```
for link in links:
    print link
```

and so on. But you can only access things in whatever order it defines; you can't necessarily do `link[5]`, and once you've gone through the iterator, it's used up.

A generator is, for most purposes, just an iterator that doesn't necessarily know all its results in advance. This is very useful in [generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension), and you can actually write very simple functions that return generators with the yield keyword:

```
def odds():
    x = 1
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 2

 os = odds()
 os.next() # returns 1
 os.next() # returns 3
```

This is a Good Thing because it means that you don't have to store all of your data in memory at once (which for `odds()` would be impossible...), and if you only need the first few elements of the result you don't have to bother computing the rest. The [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) has a bunch of handy functions for dealing with iterators.

---

Anyway, if you just want to print out the contents of `links`, you can turn it into a list with the `list()` function (which takes an iterable and returns a list of its elements):

```
 print list(links)
```

or make a list of strings with a list comprehension:

```
 print [l.url for l in list(links)]
```

or walk over its elements and print them out:

```
 for l in links:
      print l.url
```

But note that after you do this, `links` will be "exhausted" - so if you want to actually do anything with it, you'll need to get it again.

Maybe the simplest option is to immediately turn it into a list and not worry about it being an iterator at all:

```
links = list(br.links(url_regex="/people/"))
```

---

Also, you're obviously not yet getting links that have the class you want. There might be some `mechanize` trick to do an "or" here, but a nifty way to do it using sets and generator expressions would be something like this:

```
 links = set(l.url for l in br.links(url_regex='/people/'))
 links.update(l.url for l in br.get_links_with_class('office-holder'))
```

Obviously replace `get_links_with_class` with the real way to get those links. Then you'll end up with a set of all the link URLs that have `/people/` in their URL and/or have the class `office-holder`, with no duplicates. (Note that you can't put the `Link` objects in the set directly because they're not hashable.)